# Which noun does the participle phrase modify?

Tags: phrases, punctuation, participle-phrases

I am unable to understand this question (number 11). I think that option A is correct as it working as a participle phrase. But I am not sure which noun does it modify. The correct answer is C.

[image: Please refer question 11]

Given that the answer to Question 10 is J, the original passage looks like this:

> Of the numerous ironing board inventors, Sarah Boone is credited by the US Patent and Trademark **Office, turning** the tide against homemade boards.

and the answer key says it should be changed to:

> Of the numerous ironing board inventors, Sarah Boone is credited by the US Patent and Trademark **Office with turning** the tide against homemade boards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase

> credited with *something*

is an idiomatic expression meaning the subject was responsible for the idea or implementation of *something*.

> Stephen Jobs is credited with popularizing the use of sleek design in smart phones.

Your example #11

> Sarah Boone is credited ... with turning the tide against homemade boards

is saying Sarah Boone is responsible for stopping homemade ironing boards which may have been fire hazards.

Comment: "Sarah Boone is credited ... with turning" can we neglect the words that are between "credited" and "with" ? Don't you think that the unnecessary phrase should have been put in commas?

Comment: No, because the omitted words are "by the USPTO". The "by" phrase in a passive construction is not parenthetical, but integral to the meaning. It could be set off with commas, but the emphasis would change: instead of talking about her being credited by the USPTO with ... , it would mean that she was credited with ... , and only remark in passing that it was the USPTO that had so credited her.